# Initialization of DP array(whether inside or outside the function)

Tags: algorithm, function, dynamic-programming

I was solving a problem related to DP [https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/description/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).
Below is my code which is throwing TLE when i'm initialising the dp array inside the function.

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    int climbStairs(int n) {
        
        int dp[46];      
        if(dp[n]!=0) return dp[n]; 
        if(n==1 ||n==2) return n;
        dp[n]=climbStairs(n-1)+climbStairs(n-2);
        return dp[n];
    }
};
```

But when I intialised the dp array outside the scope of function my solution got accepted. I want to know why this is happening.
Below shown is my accepted solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int dp[46];
    int climbStairs(int n) {
        
       
        if(dp[n]!=0) return dp[n]; 
        if(n==1 ||n==2) return n;
        dp[n]=climbStairs(n-1)+climbStairs(n-2);
        return dp[n];
    }
};
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function then debug it line by line, you will soon understand why.

Comment: You initialize every time you call this function, i.e you're making a new array for each call and don't even use those arrays (on the next call).. simple as that